# Google Maps API KEY does not work

Tags: java, android, maps

I have a couple of doubts with my work:

I'm working on an Android application, and I have to use Google Maps for this, 
I have created and API KEY from my keystore located at `C:/Users/UserName/.android/debug.keystore`
with the following line on cmd

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:/Users/Username/.android/debug.keystore"
```

I already got the SHA-1 from the keystore and generated the api key.

the following is to set the Android Manifest, so it looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<permission android:name="emcor.pre.procesoelectoral.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="emcor.pre.procesoelectoral.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/maps_api_key"/>
```

At the moment I start the activity with the map on it, it just render a blank background with Google watermark and zoom buttons with this error message on logcat

```
10-27 14:48:50.499    4211-4275/emcor.pre.procesoelectoral E/REQUEST﹕ In Error Mode
10-27 14:48:50.500    4211-4275/emcor.pre.procesoelectoral E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I have been researching this issue all over the web and I have no conclusions yet, is my api key well generated?

Comment: As far as I know, an API key has always to be created inside the developer console. Enlighten me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's right, I created it at Google Developers Console with my SHA-1 fingerprint

Comment: Have you checked your network connection?

Comment: Yes, I have a wi-fi connection established and 3G, I tried re-generating my api key a couple times, but, is the same

Comment: Have you enabled the API in the developer console?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that, created a project and enabled the Google Maps V2 API, then, I created my api key

Comment: testing on an actual device or emulator ?

Comment: I am actually testing on a Moto G device, I'm still wondering if my api key has been generated incorrectly

Answer (score -1):

After you change your API key you must clear your app data

Clear Application Data with: Go to S*ettings>Application Manager>Select Your Application > Click on Clear Data*

Comment: I already tried that, also uninstalling and installing the application

Comment: Is your debug.keystore the same your IDE use to sign the apk?